# How can I reduce it to more efficient way

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

**Requirement** - To show the list of things as follows in the UI (angular 6) which includes the sorting as Maximum counts first and if the counts are same then arrange them alphabetically (A-Z).

```
Aditya (4) // numbers are clickable links
Bankesh (3)
Bikaji (3)
Zebra (1)
```

I have an data as follows :

```
thingsNames = [];


const data = [ 
  {loc: 'abs', things : ['Aditya','Bankesh'] }, 
  {loc: 'abc', things: ['Aditya','Bikaji'] }, 
  {loc: 'abz', things: ['Aditya','Bikaji'] }, 
  {loc: 'dsd', things: ['Aditya','Bankesh']}, 
  {loc: 'fre', things: ['Bankesh','Bikaji','Zebra'] } 
]
```

How I achieved the above requirements is as follows:

```
const names = [];
_.forEach(data, (item) => {
  _.forEach(item.things, (thing) => {
    names.push(thing); //this will be in the same array.here the output is names = ['Aditya', 'Aditya',Aditya','Aditya','Bankesh','Bankesh','Bankesh','Bikaji','Bikaji','Bikaji','Zebra' ]; // it is //not arranged i just wrote it likewise.

    const toString = ([name, count]) => `${name}(${count})`;
    const entry = _.entries(_.countBy(names));
    const finalResult = _.orderBy(entry, [1, 0], ['desc', 'asc']); // sorting i have achieved here
    const result = _.map(finalResult, toString); // this create everytime a new array.
    this.thingsNames = result;
  });
});
```

The o/p with the above code is like Aditya(4)... in an array, I displayed it in UI as follows:

```
    <div *ngFor = "let thingsName of thingsNames">

    {{thingsName}}          

    </div>
```

```
                   // shows as 
                  // Aditya(4)
                  // Bankesh(3)
                  // Bikaji(3)
                  // Zeebra(1)
```

The Problem I am facing is that , if the data contains 100 rows then it will waste too much memory in the system which is not a good practice,
secondly I wanted the count and name as different keys so that i can make counts as clickable.

How can i achieve them.

Comment: try using a Map instead of a simple array [MDN Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), am not talking about map function... this will be wvery handy to even pick up an add counts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid the need reorder the entries, but you can refactor the code by using `_.flatMap()` instead of nested `_.forEach()` calls, and skipping the redundant `_.map()` at the end:

```js
const data = [ 
  {loc: 'abs', things : ['Aditya','Bankesh'] }, 
  {loc: 'abc', things: ['Aditya','Bikaji'] }, 
  {loc: 'abz', things: ['Aditya','Bikaji'] }, 
  {loc: 'dsd', things: ['Aditya','Bankesh']}, 
  {loc: 'fre', things: ['Bankesh','Bikaji','Zebra'] } 
]

const entries = _.entries(_.countBy(_.flatMap(data, 'things')))
const thingsNames = _.orderBy(entries, [1, 0], ['desc', 'asc']);

console.log(thingsNames)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Don't map the results, but use ngFor to create the text and link:

```
<div *ngFor = "let thingsName of thingsNames">

  {{thingsName[0]}} (<a href="/url" >({{thingsName[1]}})</a>)

</div>
```

Comment: very thanks Ori Drori :) it helped, but is this the best possible way in which we can save memory if the data could be huge ?

Comment: If the data is huge your problem would be rendering, which can be solved with virtual scrolling. The other problem would be preparing the data - mainly sorting it, and storing it. You might want to consider indexeddb, which might help you with that.

Comment: Is there anyway in the frontend ?

Comment: It's all in the FE - indexeddb is a browser db

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [

  {
    loc: 'abs',
    things: ['Aditya', 'Bankesh']
  },
  {
    loc: 'abc',
    things: ['Aditya', 'Bikaji']
  },
  {
    loc: 'abz',
    things: ['Aditya', 'Bikaji']
  },
  {
    loc: 'dsd',
    things: ['Aditya', 'Bankesh']
  },
  {
    loc: 'fre',
    things: ['Bankesh', 'Bikaji', 'Zebra']
  }

]
let map = new Map();
arr.forEach(item => {
  item.things.forEach(val => {
    if (map.has(val)) {
      let count = map.get(val);
      map.set(val, count + 1);
    } else map.set(val, 1);
  })
})
console.log(map) // see console log
//then sort map according to your logic
```

and in your angular code

```
 <div *ngFor = "let thingsName of map | keyvalue">

    {{thingsName.key}} <a /*to your route*/ >({{thingsName.value}})</a>         

    </div>
```

[keyvalue](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe for your reference
NOTE: use pollyfills for map to work in older versions of browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce method here.

```js
    const data = [
        { loc: 'abs', things: ['Aditya', 'Bankesh'] },
        { loc: 'abc', things: ['Aditya', 'Bikaji'] },
        { loc: 'abz', things: ['Aditya', 'Bikaji'] },
        { loc: 'dsd', things: ['Aditya', 'Bankesh'] },
        { loc: 'fre', things: ['Bankesh', 'Bikaji', 'Zebra'] }
    ];
    const reducedData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const things = curr.things;
        things.forEach(val=>{
            acc[val] = (acc[val] || 0) + 1; 
        })
        return acc;
    }, {})
    console.log(reducedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

A lodash way:

```
import { flatten as _flatten, countBy as _countBy } from 'lodash';

const data = [
        { loc: 'abs', things: ['Aditya', 'Bankesh'] },
        { loc: 'abc', things: ['Aditya', 'Bikaji'] },
        { loc: 'abz', things: ['Aditya', 'Bikaji'] },
        { loc: 'dsd', things: ['Aditya', 'Bankesh'] },
        { loc: 'fre', things: ['Bankesh', 'Bikaji', 'Zebra'] }
    ];

console.log(_countBy(_flatten(data.map(entry => entry.things))));
```